# C: Get input and store it into a char without any libraries

Tags: c, input, libraries

Is it possible to get a input and store it into a char without any additionals libraries?

So `gets()` and other functions like this are not available.

Any ideas?

Comment: [read](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read) from `stdin` (usually fd `0`).

Comment: How do you define "library"? The standard library is standard, it's typically available.

Comment: It's on a "own" OS. So there are only some supporting libraries. For example: To display something and to regonize the keyboard.

Comment: if input is a parameter passed on execution - then yes. through `char**args`

Comment: It will be difficult to help you if you use non standard lib and non standard os... how can we know what exists and how it works ?

Comment: Read it via command line!

Comment: Yes, the point is, that there is no usefull lib. So i have to make it from ground up. The only thing i was able to program, is the print() funtction. The arch is: elf_i386

Comment: Commenting on critical information like "only thing i was able to program, is the print() unction." is not as useful as making that part of the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *only* specified "input" available to a program without libraries is through `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`.  [@j2ko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39388112/c-get-input-and-store-it-into-a-char-without-any-libraries#comment66103278_39388112)  [@kiner_shah](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39388112/c-get-input-and-store-it-into-a-char-without-any-libraries/39392025#comment66103549_39388112)

The only "output" available is `int main()`'s return value.